# Query doesn't work in Excel with WHERE statement (Excel 2016)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, excel-2016, information-schema

I have an Information_Schema query that runs perfectly in SSMS returning 100 records:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM [DB-LIVE].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'ABC CAN$Customer' 
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
```

The query returns zero records in Excel when run as an OLE DB Query.

I can get the query to return results in Excel if I remove the `WHERE` statement:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM [DB-LIVE].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
```

How can I fix my `WHERE` statement so that the my query will run in Excel?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this query other than table names that have spaces and special characters. But that query should work just fine.

Comment: May be try with adding [] delimiter as =>

WHERE TABLE_NAME = '[ABC CAN$Customer]'